# jquery bound event doesn't fire on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, iphone

Heyho,
i want to bind an event to a HTML tablerow. This seems to work on common desktop browsers but not on mobile phone browsers. Tested on iPhone 6 and some Android devices.
[Here's a related fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLon8sd7/7/),
and this is my code:

```
$("body").on("click", "tr", function(){
      //do something 
})
```

I can't use an click event on the tablerow itself (which seems to work) because the table is generated after pageload.
Thanks for your input.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in to a $(document).ready(function(){})?

Comment: @Gezzasa - Yes, the code is inside of it.

Comment: If the answer below doesnt work. try to put your script at the bottom of your page. Binding click functions do have some issues with mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:
Adding a

> cursor: pointer;

CSS style to the tablerow will fix the problem.
I don't understand why, because i don't even have a cursor on mobile devices but it works, so what.

```js
$("body").on("click", "tr.prim", function(){
      $(".sec").fadeToggle();  
})
```

```css
.sec {
    display: none;
}
.prim {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">
    <tr height="100" class="prim" bgcolor="#ffb7b7">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="100" class="sec" bgcolor="#ef4a4a">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="100" class="sec" bgcolor="#ef4a4a">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```